# How to format any extensions as .css with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, semantic-ui, prettier

As I am using **Semantic UI**, most CSS is written in `.override` files. I need Visual Studio to treat these files as `.css` extension and format accordingly (with distinctive colors and auto format).

Does anyone know how to config this in Visual Studio Code? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Add a `.scss` extension after the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Go to user settings and add a file association with

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.override": "css"
}
```

Section

More info here [VS Code File associations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)